# F# - Pattern matching discriminated union and accessing object's properties

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

from F# tour i have this example

```
type Person = {
    First : string
    Last  : string
 }

/// A Discriminated Union of 3 different kinds of employees
type Employee =
    | Engineer of engineer: Person
    | Manager of manager: Person * reports: List<Employee>
    | Executive of executive: Person * reports: List<Employee> * assistant: Employee

let rec findDaveWithOpenPosition(emps: List<Employee>) = 
    emps
    |> List.filter(function 
                    | Manager({First =  "Dave"}, []) -> true
                    | Executive({First = "Dave"}, [], _) -> true
                    | _ -> false
                    )
```

However I would like to get access to object after matching object, something like this:

```
let rec findDaveWithOpenPos2(emps: List<Employee>) =
    List.filter (fun (e:Employee) ->
                    match e with
                        | Manager({First = "Dave"}, []) -> e.Last.Contains("X") //Does not compile
                        | Executive({First = "Dave"}, [], _) -> true
                        | _ -> false
                    ) emps
```

So i would like to have statically typed "e" as Person or Employee or Manager variable on right hand side with access to it's properties.
Is it possible? Is there a better construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name the `Person` instance within the `Manager` case using `as`:

```
let rec findDaveWithOpenPos2(emps: Employee list) =
    List.filter (fun (e:Employee) ->
                    match e with
                        | Manager({First = "Dave"} as p, []) -> p.Last.Contains("X")
                        | Executive({First = "Dave"}, [], _) -> true
                        | _ -> false
                    ) emps
```

Comment: How can I refer to object `e:Employee`, not just `p:Person`? Is `Manager({First = "Dave"}, []) as m-> m...` enough? `p` is after all of type 'Manager' but I have no methods for this object. Is it because there is nothing implemented? But there should be at least a `reports: Employee list` property. Or is it just tuple and this  `reports: Employee list` is not part of object `p`?

Comment: @BartekWójcik - `e` already refers to the `Employee` but it doesn't have a `Last` member. `p` has type `Person`. There is no `Manager` type - `Manager` is a constructor of the `Employee` type.

Comment: @Lee Actually, F#'s list is called `List` and it has a type alias of `list`, so it is the right type unless you've opened `System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox - Thanks, removed that from the answer.